# Bootstrap Modal Text Click

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I want to create a Bootstrap 4 modal as shown here: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_modal.asp.

However, instead of opening the modal on a click of a button, I want to open the modal on a click of some text (probably with an `a` tag). How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need add `data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"` attributes to `a` tag instead of the button

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open modal</a>
```

Example http://jsfiddle.net/Br4sL/2/